# how to find recently modified document in lotus notes 5

Tags: java, lotus-notes

What I am trying to do is read through lotus notes 5 and export all the document in there to by local modeshape repository but once i finish reading through all the million records/ documents, the process starts reading from 1st record in lotus notes but i don't want that. i need to read only the recently modified documents in lotus notes.

my function looks something like this :

```
public void run() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "entering run");
    try {
        String pathToFolder = "";
        s = NotesFactory.createSession(host, "username", "password");
        Database db = s.getDatabase("", nsffilename);
        if (!db.isOpen()) {
            db.open();
        }
        DocumentCollection docCol = db.getAllDocuments();
        Document doc = docCol.getFirstDocument();
        while (doc != null) {
            doc = docCol.getNextDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

I found some code off internet which is posted here:
http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/c698b5888603d5cd8525704a00417105?OpenDocument

but this only works for lotus notes 8 and above.
but I am stuck with lotus notes 5.
Please let me know if there is some way that I can get recently modified documents in lotus notes 5.

Comment: It sounds like someone hasn't upgraded since [1999](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-NDHistory/), why did they wait so long?

Comment: Don't know Sir but this is just frustrating to work on this age old system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a view with a first column `@Modified` in descending sort order and use View class to read all documents - last modified first.

```
  ...
  View view = db.getView("YourViewSortedByLastModified");
  view.setAutoUpdate(false);
  Document tmpdoc;
  Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
  while (doc != null) {
    // do with your doc what you want
    tmpdoc = view.getNextDocument(doc);
    doc.recycle();
    doc = tmpdoc;
  }
```

You can break while loop when you reached document from last run.

**Don't** include in your view selection formula any function which delivers current time or date like @Now or @Today for performance reasons. It is better to list all documents and to stop loop when document from last run is reached.

The document order in a `DocumentCollection` is uncertain. Usually oldest documents are first but you can't rely on this. If you loop through a `View` document's order in view remains.

Comment: thanks for your answer Knut, I will get the lotus notes team implement this view and will mark this reply as correct answer if thinks start working as expected. Thanks a lot for the reply though. you just saved me a million record iteration :)

Comment: Hi Knut,Can you please tell me what should be the query to create a view in lotus notes for getting the modified records first. Sorry I am not a lotus notes resource and the person who can do it is not the same location where I work. I would really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: Tell Notes person that you need a view with `SELECT @All` (for all documents in database) and one descending sorted column with formula `@Modified`.

Comment: You are the man sir. Thanks for all your help. I will ask the lotus notes resource to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting a document collection of all the documents in the database, you could instead create a view that shows only the recently modified documents and loop through that view.

Comment: Hi Ken,
I am going to implement that as per Knut's and your recommendation. Hope things work as expected. thanks for the reply though